# iPhone how to submit an app with a non-glossy retina display icon?

Tags: iphone, xcode, icons, app-store

I noticed that all of my attempts at a retina display 114x114 application icon image automatically have a gradient shadow overlaid on top of them. My icon already has transparency over a black background, and the second gradient shadow makes the background look less black

I noticed that quite a few apps have their icons appear "flat", having no shadow. **Is there some flag that I can set in my project to request this semi-circular shadow effect to not be applied to the icon?**

Updated:
Xcode 4.2 iOS 5.0 as deployment target.
Only 1 deployment target.
For some reason the suggested solutions do not seem to work. 
I have The property added to the target. I see the boolean of YES for both the raw UIPrerendered icon and the "icon already includes gloss effects". I've replaced the icon files and tried different icons.  I've uninstalled the app from the development device and reinstalled it. I did a clean. The gloss effect is still there. What am I forgetting?

Update 2: After 45 minutes of messing and losing my sanity, I noticed that there's another Dictionary in the Plist:

```
Icon files(iOS5). Within that is a Primary Icon Dictionary,
```

within that is **another declaration** of "Icon already includes gloss effect". That one is set to NO. Setting that one to YES removes gloss, and makes my icon look awesome :) My guess is that as I migrated the project to iOS5, that key was added

PS. While on the topic of icons, I built an [icon maker app for iPhone](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/icon-maker++-for-iphone/id531687111?ls=1&mt=8) that allows me to vary the intensity of the gloss effect, as well as include/exclude some icon elements from the gloss. I still have to tell xCode that my icon is "pre-rendered", but I control the gloss effect.

Comment: You are correct. it works for me.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After 45 minutes of messing and losing my sanity, I noticed that there's another Dictionary in the Plist:

**Icon files(iOS5). Within that is a Primary Icon Dictionary**,

**within that is another declaration of "Icon already includes gloss effect"**. That one is set to NO. Setting that one to YES removes gloss, and makes my icon look awesome :) My guess is that as I migrated the project to iOS5, that key was added

Comment: I also had a flag to set to `YES` which was `CFBundleIcons~ipad`->`CFBundlePrimaryIcon`->`UIPrerenderedIcon`

Answer (score 17):

In your Info.plist for your target add the following attribute.

[image]

Comment: For some reason this does not work. I've updated the question with the steps that I've taken, the gloss effect is still there :/ I'm using Xcode 4.2 iOS5

Comment: Choose clean from the build menu. Then try again.

Comment: I've updated my question with the answer which works for Xcode 4.2.1 and iOS5.0

Comment: @AlexStone In any case you should accept an answer to close out the question and keep your acceptance rating high. If  feel your findings are more relevant than the answer I provided you should create an answer yourself and accept it.

Answer (score 7):

on ios5 (and higher) just go on Targets-->Summary-->App Icons und check on "Prerendered" - glossy effect is then away

Comment: checking "Prerendered" adds "Icon already includes gloss effects"=>YES to your info.plist in "Icon files(iOS5)">"Primary Icon"

Answer (score 7):

Follow the Alex Stone answer and then you need do the below steps if you are using assests catalog to remove gloss effect

To remove the gloss:

- Go to the project files navigator in Xcode.
- Click on the asset catalog file (Images.xcassets)
- Bring up the attributes panel (typically, the far right) when viewing the asset catalog
- Click the box labeled 'iOS icon is pre-rendered'

Performing these steps adds the following toward the end of the file Contents.json inside the asset catalog folder:

"properties" : {
    "pre-rendered" : true
  }

Comment: thanks! I had the utilities panel closed after switching to asset catalogs for the first time. Didn't know there were options in there

Answer (score 4):

Set the following flag in your info.plist to **TRUE**.

[image]

```
UIPrerenderedIcon (Icon already includes gloss effects)
```

If you don't have it, just add it to your `info.plist`. Use "Show raw keys/values" to show the name of the attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You need to go to the **SUMMARY tab** for your project and check the "**Prerendered**" checkbox next to the icons themselves.  Boom, Bob's your Uncle.  So they say.  Nudge nudge, wink, wink, know-what-I-mean ?  See Screenshot

[image]